# Android In-App Billing: Not restoring already purchased Item

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I've implemented in-app billing in my app, when I purchased a non-consumable item, It works fine for that particular version of the app.

But when I update the version of the app, I started getting purchased status as null. (which I guess is "Item not purchased").

Here is my code:

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");

        // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        // Is it a failure?
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }

        // Do we have the premium upgrade?
        Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(C.PLAY_STORE_ITEM);
        boolean mIsPremium = (premiumPurchase != null);
        Log.d(TAG, "User is " + (mIsPremium ? "PREMIUM" : "NOT PREMIUM"));
    }
};
```

I'm getting null over here `Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(C.PLAY_STORE_ITEM);`